# List data that are not in relation with the current activerecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_tests

  has_many :tests, through: :group_tests
end

class GroupTest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :test
end

class Test < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_tests
  has_many :groups, through: :group_tests
end
```

I have this database design. I need to list only those tests that are not added into a group.

Lets say we have 6 tests (Test 1, Test 2, Test 4 ....) and 3 Groups(Group 1, Group 2, Group 3)

We add 3 tests(Test 1, Test 2, Test 3) to Group 1.

Now I want to fetch only those tests that are not present in group 1 which is Test 4, Test 5, Test 6

```
group = Group.find(id) // lets say group 1
// find tests that are not added to this group
```

Comment: Try with this
`group_test_ids = group.tests.ids`
`tests = Test.where.not(id: group_test_ids)`

Comment: @ts good one :) .I think I should not name a table `group`. It conflicts with a built in actirecord method

Comment: @ts let me try your solnution after i fix it but i am sure it will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you find test ids which belong to particular group and then using [not](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain/not) or you can also use @Vasilisa query using joins.

```
group_test_ids = group.tests.ids #test ids which belongs to group

tests = Test.where.not(id: group_test_ids) # tests which not contain that group
```

One liner

```
tests = Test.where.not(id: group.tests.ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it in one line.

```
Test.left_outer_joins(:groups).where.not(groups: {id: id})
```